# Y a-t-il un équivalent de vocabulary.com en français?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

Vocabulary.com est un site incroyable qui personnalise un programme d'apprentissage de vocabulaire pour les anglophones de tous niveaux, de niveau débutant jusqu'à niveau très avancé. Y a-t-il d'équivalent en français?

Je ne cherche pas quelque chose qui soit aussi avancé que vocabulary.com, mais je cherche un service qui envoie des mots de vocabulaire français chaque jour ou semaine basé sur le niveau de langue de l'utilisateur. Y a-t-il un tel service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose, mais le service le plus proche que j'ai trouvé est [Projet Voltaire](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr) qui perfectionne l'orthographie et toute compétence y relié : le vocabulaire des mots semblables, la grammaire, etc. Ce n'est pas gratuit, mais je trouve le prix des applis de téléphone intelligent valent bien leur cout. De plus, il n'envoie pas des mots périodiquement, mais on peut suivre le programme à son propre pas, ce qui me convient bien.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/index.php?go2=11 est un site qui comporte beaucoup de ressources (cours et exercices). Il y a aussi la possibilité de s'abonner à une newsletter hebdomadaire.

Comment: Merci. Je me suis maintenant abonné à leur bulletin. Après la réception du premier bulletin, je vais vérifier si c'est bien ce que je cherche ou non.

Comment: Après être abonné pendant plus que deux mois, malheureusement, francaisfacile.com n'est pas ce que je cherche. Étant donné que Vocabulary.com est tellement unique, je ne crois pas qu'il existe une pareille ressource en français.

Comment: Une autre ressource semblable à francaisfacile.com est french.about.com, mais c'est tout redigé en anglais. Pourtant, pour les anglophones (comme moi), c'est une ressource excellente en général (mais ce n'est non plus la même chose que Vocabulary.com).